# Почему так сложилось, что правильным ударением считается "по средАм"?

Tags: орфоэпия

Размышляя над этим, понял, что обычно, видимо, ударение в дательном падеже то же, что и в слове во множественном числе. По крайней мере, перебирая слова, я не нашёл пока больше исключений.

Почему же действительно тогда правильно "по средАм" несмотря на "срЕды"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этот пример можно проверить **по акцентным классам существительных**.

Существительное "среда" имеет два значения: (1) вещество, заполняющее пространство и (2) день недели.

Среда (1) - это существительное **класса D** (например, число) **с переходом ударения с окончания на основу**: в ед. числе ударение на окончании, во мн. числе - на основе: средЫ, средЕ, средУ и срЕды,  срЕдам, срЕдами, о срЕдах.

Среда (2) - это существительное может относиться **к двум акцентным классам:** класс D1 (душа) и B2 (гора). **Класс D1 очень похож на класс D и отличается только формой В. п. ед. ч.: душА - дУшу, средА - срЕду.**

В этом случае среда (2) фактически копирует все формы среды (1), кроме одной: поместить **в определенную средУ,** но встретиться **в срЕду**. Тогда мы должны говорить: по срЕдам, срЕдами и о срЕдах. Таким образом, **общая тенденция изменения ударения (от средАм к срЕдам) направлена на унификацию фонетических форм для двух значений слова.**

А вот акцентный класс B2- это разновидность класса B (в классе В все ударения в ед. и мн. числе падают на окончание), но с колебаниями в  И. п. и В. п. В этом случае мы должны говорить: в срЕду (В. п.), но: по средАм, средАми, о средАх (старый вариант произношения).

В настоящий момент допускаются оба варианта.

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё разложили по полочкам! Так "по средАм" — более старый вариант?

Comment: Из ответа slava1947: У Аванесова в 1955 году (Русское литературное ударение и произношение) было только средАм, но четверть века спустя в его Орфоэпическом словаре русского языка были отмечены как нормативные уже оба ударения — и средАм, и срЕдам.

Answer (score 2):

> ...что правильным ударением считается “по средАм”?

.

[***Русский орфографический словарь***](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0&all=x) (Лопатин и др.) правильным считает и по ***средАм,*** и по ***срЕдам.***

.

Так же считают и авторы ***Большого орфоэпического словаря*** (Каленчук М. Л., Касаткин Л. Л., Касаткина Р. Ф. "Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка. Литературное произношение и ударение начала ХХI века: норма и её варианты" , М.: АСТ-ПРЕСС КНИГА, 2012):

.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

.

Оба ударения допускает и *Зализняк* (см. его ***Грамматический словарь русского языка***).

.

У *Аванесова* в 1955 году ***(Русское литературное ударение и произношение)*** было только *средАм,* но  четверть века спустя в его ***Орфоэпическом словаре русского языка*** были отмечены как нормативные уже оба ударения  — и ***средАм***, и ***срЕдам:***

.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

> Размышляя над этим, понял, что обычно, видимо, ударение в дательном падеже то же, что и в слове во множественном числе. По крайней мере, перебирая слова, я не нашёл пока больше исключений.
>
> Почему же действительно тогда правильно "по средАм" несмотря на "срЕды"?

Не знаю, что Вы там искали, но парадигма совершенно очевидная.

РукА - рУки - по рукАм.
НогА - нОги - по ногАм.
ГоловА - гОловы - по головАм.
(это бесспорные примеры).

КопнА - кОпны - по копнАм.
СтенА - стЕны - по стенАм.
МежА - мЕжи - по межАм.
(Лопатин, правда, даёт как равноправное "по кОпнам", "по стЕнам" и "по мЕжам").
СлезА-слёзы-по слезАм.
и проч.

Ну и что тут для чего исключение?

В целом могу когда-то нормативная в подобных случая форма дательного множественного  уступает современной с ударение на основе. Отсюда и колебания в форме, отмечаемая Лопатиным и другими авторами. Но этот процесс у разных слов занимает разное время. Сравните, например: "Открылась бездна звезд полна;// Звездам числа нет, бездне дна." (Ломоносов) при современном "звёздам", (разг.) "слёзам"

Comment: Я не искал, вспоминал просто, но недолго, и поэтому не вспомнил ни одного такого примера, как у вас.(